# MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener not called on older devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm having major issues with the media player.  I have come across this question on SO [Android Mediaplayer OnInfo and OnError not called on older Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139388/android-mediaplayer-oninfo-and-onerror-not-called-on-older-devices)  however, this does not address my issue.

[Android VideoView MediaPlayer OnInfoListener - events not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882815/android-videoview-mediaplayer-oninfolistener-events-not-fired)

`MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener` is called on my newer devices (Samsung Galaxy S4, Sony Xperia Z3, Nexus 5), so I'm not sure why this isn't being called on the older devices (samsung s3 mini).  In the 2nd linked post it says that its a HLS error, however I'm unsure how this is the case, is this something that has been fixed in the OS?

I need to be able to dismiss the progress dialog and doing it in the `onPrepared` method is too early as the video isn't ready to start.

Also if the video lags, I need to display a progress dialog and the only way of getting the info is via the `onInfoListener`.

Is there any way around this???

Answer (score 1):

Its a known bug, please check here,
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42767

and there is accepted answer of the same question,
[OnInfoListener is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835813/oninfolistener-is-never-called)

hope this will help you.